# "FROM" error in MySQL update query

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm using MySQL workbench trying to add values to a new column (osTNR) in an existing table (OS) from an existing table in the database (TNRs).  I've taken the below syntax from another response on Stack Overflow, but it's still not working.

```
UPDATE OS
SET OS.osTNR = TNRs.TNR
FROM OS INNER JOIN TNRs
ON OS.osTerm = TNRs.thesaurusTerm;
```

Before I run it, it highlights that it isn't expecting a "FROM" in this query.  When I run it I get:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM OS INNER JOIN TNRs ON OS.osTerm = TNRs.thesaurusTerm' at line 3"

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE OS
INNER JOIN TNRs
  ON OS.osTerm = TNRs.thesaurusTerm
SET
  OS.osTNR = TNRs.TNR;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
UPDATE OS 
INNER JOIN TNRs ON OS.osTerm = TNRs.thesaurusTerm
SET OS.osTNR = TNRs.TNR;
```

Comment: Thanks! - I knew it would be soemthing straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UPDATE OS, TNRs
SET OS.osTNR = TNRs.TNR
WHERE OS.osTerm = TNRs.thesaurusTerm;
```

It would definitely work. Here `OS` and `TNRs` are the table names.